# Entity Framework Migration HasKey(x => x.Id) is not generating Identity column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been using this C# solution for years generating migrations but I have never seen this happen before. For all of my other entity types this is working fine. This is entity framework 6.4.

Example of a working mapping:

```
    public sealed class PresentationMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Presentation>
    {
        public PresentationMapping()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.Id);
```

Generates this Migration:

```
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Presentation",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
```

However for this table it does not set `identity: true`.

```
    public sealed class ProductDetailSnapshotMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductDetailSnapshot>
    {
        public ProductDetailSnapshotMapping()
        {
            HasKey(t => t.Id);
```

Generates this migration:

```
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.ProductDetailSnapshot",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Long(nullable: false),
```

With no `identity:true` set. I have tried all manner of dropping and re-adding the migration and this table refuses to set `identity:true`.

Here's my class definition. Every other entity I'm using also inherits from this `Entity` class to define the `Id` the exact same way.

```
    public class ProductDetailSnapshot : ProductEntity
    {
        public long ExternalSupplierId { get; set; }
        public long ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductDetailJson { get; set; }
    }
    public abstract class ProductEntity : Entity
    {
        public long PresentationProductId { get; set; }
        public PresentationProduct PresentationProduct { get; set; }
    }
    public abstract class Entity : IEntity
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
    }
```

I know I could force it by manually changing the migration, but I want the mapping to properly represent this, and in fact I actually need to generate a new migration in order to fix this in another environment so I'd like EF to generate the script to do this for me.

Why is my table refusing to set this Id column as identity?  How can I get the mapping to force an identity column on Id?

Comment: Have you tried `.Property(t=>t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);`

Comment: Yes thanks I am about to post an answer I found regarding that

Answer (score 0):

I found I could specifically state the the id as being DbGenerated Identity which solved the problem.

The base of the mapping classes we use (removed from the question for brevity) did not explicitly state that Id should be used as an identity column. Somewhere EF was inferring that, and for some odd reason it was just not firing for that table. Adding this line to my base `EntityMap` constructor fixed it.

```
HasKey(t => t.Id);
Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

My only guess to why this is happening is that the word "Snapshot" has some special coding in Entity Framework and it's ignoring some kind of convention because of that name. I think there is some special class that's like "DatabaseSnapshot" that could potentially be the cause, but this is pure speculation.

I tried changing it to `ProductDetailSnapshotasdf` to test this theory but the problem persisted. I didn't try removing `Snapshot` completely from the name as I had found the solution above by this time, but I'd be very curious to know the real cause here.

UPDATE: I found the true cause. I configured this `Snapshot` table as a one-to-one with `PresentationProduct`. I was trying to configure this with a dedicated FK column `Snapshot.PresentationProductId`, but the way I had it mapped was that EF was thinking that `Snapshot.Id` would be a PK/FK pointing to `PresentationProduct.Id`. Thus, since it was PK/FK, EF was not assigning it an identity column.

I need to choose which method of FK I want to do which should help me fix the migration.